# Doctrine2 - what DQL to use?

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, dql

The first entity called `BUNDLE`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Course\Course
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\Course", mappedBy="bundles")
 */
private $courses;
```

The second entity is called `COURSE`

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Bundle\Bundle
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Bundle\Bundle", inversedBy="courses")
 */
    private $bundles;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of \Akademie\Course\CourseDate
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\CourseDate", mappedBy="course")
 */
    private $courseDates;

/**
 * @var int
 * @Column(type="boolean")
 */
    private $hidden;
```

and the third is called `COURSEDATE`

```
/**
 * @var \Akademie\Course\Course
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Akademie\Course\Course", inversedBy="courseDates")
 * @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
    private $course;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Column(type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
 */
    private $beginDate;
```

I have parameter `course` and I need to get all `bundles`, which contains this `course`. What's more, all other `courses` in that `bundle` has to have `courseDate` newer than current date and can't be *hidden*. Otherwise I don't want to get this bundle. I hope it is clear now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a repository (bundle of entity BUNDLE for example), you have to create a custom method :

```
public function myMethod($course){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("b")
                       ->join("b.course", "c")
                       ->join("c.courseDates", "cd")
                       ->Where("c = :course")
                       ->andWhere(" cd.beginDate > :now ")
                       ->andWhere("c.hidden = 1")// if 1 means not hidden
                       ->setParameter(":course", $course)
                       ->setParameter(":now", new \DateTime('now'));
```

And then, in your controller, you have to do something like that :

```
$bundles = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('namespace of your BUNDLE entity')->myMethod($course);
```

Comment: I have tried it and the date doesn't take a affect. It still give me bundles with old courses.

Comment: All my datetime variable have this annotations :

 /**
  *
  * @var string $subscription_date
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="variable_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
  * @Assert\DateTime()
  **/
 private $variable_date;

With this use : use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; and it's working. I don't know how to use datetimets in symfony, but are you sure the data in your database is of the same type ?